# Drupal view to list nodes and comments

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-comments

I want to create a view that shows the latest posts in a forum and also any latest comments. The comments and the posts would all show in the same view. Is it possible for me to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence: no. Views requires you to choose **one main resource** in the first step: you there (amongst others) choose to go with either nodes, or comments.

However, with some (ugly) configuration, you can load the comments that go with nodes. Each result would look like, Node - Comment, e.g.:

- Can I have cheesburgers - First!
- Can I have cheesburgers - No, I was first!!!111oneone
- Can I have cheesburgers - LAME.

and so on. With some styling, you can then get it to show comments and nodes in separate rows.

However, this is ugly and hackish. My advise: write a simple module that either exposes a block, or a menu+page, and do two simple (and light) queries on the database: `SELECT nid, title, ... FROM {nodes} LIMIT 10` and `SELECT nid, name AS title, ... FROM {comments} LIMIT 10` then mix these two up. Or, with some (more complex) SQL magic, you could even join the two tables and create fancy results that e.g. order by created date of either nodes or comments.

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I like your solution, however, I think this may take me a little longer than i was expecting and may just go down the route of just choosing to display forum posts. But I have learnt something. I'm surprised there isn't a module for this!

Answer (score 1):

With Drupal 7 you can add a relationship Last comment and then add that field to the view.

Comment: Thanks Kari, that sounds straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I've seen is to use [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) to "attach" a wholly separate view with PHP code. See [comment #4](http://drupal.org/node/636762#comment-2638922) for the code (in [a request for this feature in Views](http://drupal.org/node/636762). for a code example).

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for your answer. I don't think in this instance it will quite work for me as I want to sort the nodes and the comments by the date they were posted.

Comment: There is now a module so you can embed a view in a view field - https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view. I used this quite recently and it wasn't as complicated as I thought, even with arguments being passed.

Comment: @Ben I am exactly in search of the same problem. Do you mind posting the solution? I assume you have a view to show all latest topics and within that you have a field view that queries for top N comments for that topic. I also need "view more comments" link, like link, time elapsed since the comment was posted.